# handling dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery

i´m new developing on asp.net mvc, and even newer using jquery, so this is my problem: i have a few dropdown list that are filled dinamically using the data of another dropdown or textbox, and the data of those drop down is used for another drop down, like a chain, my problem rigth now is that the dropdown sometimes just have one answer/option, and if i try to select that option jquery doesn´t activate the $("#anything").change() event, 'cause i have just one option, how i handle it?

http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/20/sinttulolp.jpg/

for example this i need the data of the red circle for filling the blue circle, but the red circle just have one option and if i click nothing happens

code:

$(document).ready(function() {

```
            $("#tbClave1").autocomplete({
                minLength: 1,
                source: getClave1,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    updateClave2(ui.item.value);

                }
            });

            $("#tbClave1").change(function() {
                if ($("#tbClave1").val().length == 4) {
                    updateClave2($("#tbClave1").val());
                }
            });

            $("#ddClave2").change(function() {
                updateClave3($("#tbClave1").val(), $("#ddClave2").val());
                updateNombre($("#tbClave1").val(), $("#ddClave2").val());
                if ($("#ddTipoArticulo").val() == "A" ||
                    $("#ddTipoArticulo").val() == "B" ||
                    $("#ddTipoArticulo").val() == "L") {
                    updatePrecioA($("#tbClave1").val(), $("#ddClave2").val());
                } else { 
                    if ($("#ddTipoArticulo").val() == "N" ||
                         $("#ddTipoArticulo").val() == "H"){
                         updatePrecioB($("#tbClave1").val());
                    }
                }
            });

            $("#ddClave3").change(function() {
                updateClave4($("#tbClave1").val(), $("#ddClave2").val(), $("#ddClave3").val());
            });
        });
```

Edit: example of how i fill one of the dropdownlist

Jquery

function updateClave2(cod) {

```
            var dd = document.getElementById("ddClave2");
            dd.options.length = 0;
            dd.options[0] = new Option("Espere...");
            dd.selectedIndex = 0;
            dd.disabled = true;
            codigo = cod;
            tipoArt = $("#ddTipoArticulo").val();
            // Control de errores
            $("#ddClave2").ajaxError(function(event, request, settings) {
                dd.options[0] = new Option("No se Cargaron Datos");
            });
            // Obtenemos los datos...
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/GetClave2',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { words: codigo, tipoArticulo: tipoArt },
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $.each(data, function(i, item) {
                        dd.options[i] = new Option(item["clave2"], item["clave2"]);
                    });
                    dd.disabled = false;
                }
            });
        }
```

Controller

public ActionResult GetClave2(string words, string tipoArticulo){
             List mySource = miConexion.Clave2(username, password, words, tipoArticulo);
             return Json(mySource);
         }

Comment: Why not put a "Select One" option in the dropdown and make it required? This way, it triggers a selection change event.

Comment: ´cause everytime that option is different, its not always the same option, it depends of previous options, all the three dropdown list u see in the picture are filled dinamically.

Comment: You can have a "Select One" option in each dropdown along with the different options that are in each. So, everytime you select an option in dropdown1, you clear the options on dropdown2, add the Select One option and then the options that are based on dropdown1 selection.

Comment: oh sorry i didn´t understand u the first time, how i do that?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx has all the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex Mendez has wrote, adding a default item to each dropdownlist with text like "Select One" seems to be your easiest answer. You'll also need to do some handling in case the user re-selects the default "Select One option." To add default values to your .Net dropdowns try out this code:

```
YourListID.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select One", "Select One");
```

or:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="YourListID" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="true">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select One" Value="Select One" Selected="true" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

EDIT (Missed the MVC)
and in MVC when you bind your initial ViewData just make sure to have your "Select One" in the liest:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionaryList = DropDownListItems();
ViewData["ModelData"] = new SelectList(dictionaryList, "Key", "Value")
```

Comment: There is n server controls notion  in ASP.NET MVC

Comment: but if i fill the dd in the jqeury? (i´m going to edit my question whit the code)

Comment: To do it with the JQuery takes minimal work. Check this link out.http://www.billsternberger.net/asp-net-mvc/dynamically-populate-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc/

Comment: see my blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx